# Mongodb aggegration select records by $match and include additional records if query is met?

Tags: mongodb

not sure if I correctly formulated the question but I want to query for records and include additional records if criteria is met for example:

```
    $match._isTemplate = true;
    $match.$or = [
        { _shareWithUsers: { $in: [req.user._id] } },
        { _isShared: true },
    ];
```

What I need is to return records if the _isTemplate property equals to true also INCLUDE other records if **_isShared = true** or **_shareWithUsers includes requested user's id**.

The problem is that one of the $or statements must be **true** in order to return any record. In my case if $or block returns false just return templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by combining $or, $and operators.

```
{
 $and : [
               { 
                 $or : [ 
                         {_isTemplate: true},
                         {_isShared: true},
                         {_shareWithUsers: { $in: [ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxx")] }}
                       ]
               },
               { 
                  _isTemplate: true
               }
             ]
}
```

Any suggestions for improving this code?